# Whole row of the column A to be something if the column B contains something

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

Hi, when column D contains 'no', then all the rows for column C to be 'no'.

IF column D is '-' for all the rows, then remains; do nothing (so column C will, no, yes, yes).

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

Try via `groupby()` and `filter()`:

```
idx=df.groupby('A')['D'].filter(lambda x:x.eq('no').any()).index
df.loc[idx,'C']='no'
```

**OR**

Try via `groupby()` and `transfrom()` and `fillna()`:

```
df['C']=(df.groupby('A')['D'].transform(lambda x:'no' if x.eq('no').any() else float('NaN'))
           .fillna(df['C']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['C']=np.where(df['D'].eq('-'), 'yes','no)
```

or

simply

```
 df['C']=df['D'].eq('-')
```